# FN Lock in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, desktop, fn

I was designing an desktop application with Flutter-Desktop and was wondering if there was a function or other Widget that I could use to lock the 'fn' key. Currently I have not found anyway to do so, let me know if there is anything I can do!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "lock"? Like, disable?

Comment: @Dani3le_ I meant enable permanently (sorry for the confusion). I am trying to disable the Control Strip (all the MacOs Proprietary keys) on the MacOS, and figured if I enable the 'fn' key permanently and not bind the actually F1 - F9 keys to anything it should work the same as disabling the Control Strip.